# На сервере не работает curl с проксями

Tags: php, curl, proxy

Всем доброго времени суток. Проблема такая: на локальном сервере curl с проксями работает нормально и быстро. Но как только переношу скрипт на сервер, то выкидывает ошибку `Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds`. Прокси рабочие, чекал под виндой - всё ок

```
$parser = new Curl();
$parser->setUserAgent($user_agent);
$parser->setOpt(CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
$parser->setOpt(CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $logpas);
$parser->setHeader('Captcha', $code);
$parser->setOpt(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$parser->setOpt(CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__ .'/test.txt');
$parser->post('https://***.**.ru/', array('k' => $k, 'sts' => $sts));
$parser->close();
```

Для курла юзаю библиотеку [php-curl-class](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class)
Локальный сервер: Open Panel Server под виндой. 
Боевой: nginx/1.13.12 + php-fpm на какой-то из unix подобной, точно не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем копать с gzip, https, 3**. Добавьте и если не поможет сообщите:

```
$parser->setOpt(CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
$parser->setOpt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$parser->setOpt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$parser->setOpt(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: всё равно таймаут

Comment: @sbaikov  $parser->setOpt( CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5); ? А еще проверь COOKIEFILE пишется, права на запись стоят?

Comment: @sbaikov я бы еще попробовал написать curl запрос без либы на php и посмотреть отрабатывает ли он. Возможно с либой косяк.